# Use and search by indexes

Tags: sql, database, indexing, database-performance

Suppose I have this table with the index given below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Jobs]
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    [Type] SMALLINT NOT NULL,
    [Path] NVARCHAR(MAX),
    [Name] VARCHAR(256), 
)

GO
CREATE INDEX [IX_Jobs_Name_Type] ON [dbo].[Jobs] ([Name], [Type])
```

Which query will have better performance:

1.

```
UPDATE TOP((@JobCount + 3) / 4 )
Jobs WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
SET [Name] = @NName
WHERE [Name] IS NULL AND (Type = 1 OR Type = 4)
```

2. 

```
UPDATE TOP((@JobCount + 3) / 8 )
Jobs WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
SET [Name] = @NName
WHERE [Name] IS NULL AND Type = 1

UPDATE TOP((@JobCount + 3) / 8 )
Jobs WITH (ROWLOCK, READPAST)
SET [Name] = @NName
WHERE [Name] IS NULL AND Type = 4
```

Ignore in this case the correctness of the amount of rows updated,
Can doing a single search with 'or' for the Type be less effective than 2 separate queries because of the index?

Answer (score 0):

You should of course try on your database, but the database should be able to apply the index in the `OR` case.  It would be better written as:

```
WHERE [Name] IS NULL AND Type IN (1, 4)
```